# Function to check if date2 is tomorrow of date1?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, function

is there a function in vb.net or mysql that checks if date2 is the date for tomorrow of date1?

like

```
date1 = 6/4/2013
date2 = 6/5/2013

is date2 = tomorrow of date1? and also the vice versa
id date1 = yesterday of date2?
```

Is there any function for checking that in mysql and vb? or it is entirely logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do a comparison:

```
where date(date2) = date(date1) + interval 1 day
```

The `date()` function gets rid of any time element that might cause the equality to fail.

Comment: +1. @rmm04: It must be. `vb.net` doesn't have a `where` clause or support the `+ interval 1 day` in its syntax. :-)

Comment: @rmm04 . . . Yes, this is a MySQL `where` statement.  The assumption is that the two dates are columns in a table.

Comment: @ken ..hahaha. i'm just thinking too much! =)

Comment: @gordon thanks for pointing me in the right direction, just one question again..will it fail if the field has time element? will it still satisfy the condition?

Comment: @rmm04 . . . By using the `date()` function, you get rid of the time element, so it will work fine.